# Exporting MySQL database using python error

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, python-3.8

I am exporting MySQL database using python using command

```
import os
password = '1234'
os.system('mysqldump -u root -p%s ot_database > D:\\ot.sql' % password)
```

The code was executed with no errors and A **ot.sql** file is created but the **file is empty**
There is no data in **ot.sql**

***Please find the bug.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Lot of research and debugging
Finally I found the answer.
**os.system** execute ***command line commands*** on some default directory but **mysqldump** is available in some other directory so ***I must change the current directory to the directory where mysqldump is available*** using command.....

```
mysqldump_dir = 'C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\bin\\'
os.chdir(mysqldump_dir)
```